# ARGV and ARGC not returning from CRON

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, argv, argc

I am attmepting to get argv and argc from a cron job. This is what is being retunred in the $_SERVER and they are missing.

Here is the cron:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/uopynwrukuid/public_html/test_arg.php 2 200
```

Here is what I get:

```
array(13) {
  ["SHELL"]=>
  string(31) "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell"
  ["MAILTO"]=>
  string(23) "email@email.com"
  ["USER"]=>
  string(12) "uopynwrukuid"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(13) "/usr/bin:/bin"
  ["PWD"]=>
  string(18) "/home/h"
  ["LANG"]=>
  string(11) "en_US.UTF-8"
  ["SHLVL"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["HOME"]=>
  string(18) "/home/uopynwrukuid"
  ["LOGNAME"]=>
  string(12) "uopynwrukuid"
  ["_"]=>
   string(12) "/usr/bin/php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
  float(1529521741.2111)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1529521741)
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening? The script worked at some point and has now broken.

Comment: What's `var_dump($argv);` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticing you are running CPanel from your shell, CPanel has a strange habit of using php-cgi as /usr/bin/php instead of php-cli.

`php -v` should return a version and (cli) in parentheses like:

```
PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2018 12:43:14) ( NTS )
```

If you see cgi or fcgi instead, then you need to find the path to the actual cli version.  I believe this is commonly located at /usr/local/bin/php on cpanel servers.